# Gitkraken, Linux Mint and ~/.ssh keys

Tags: gitkraken

Gitkraken: 6.0.0 installed via snap.  Mint 19.1

I have started trying to use Gitkraken on Linux Mint.  I dig that Mint is using GNU keyring or some-such by default but Gitkracken seems to ignore it as the "default" ssh agent.  Command-line git ignores it as well.

If I start up a terminal window and start the openssh `ssh-agent` and then do an `ssh-add` of the keys in `~/.ssh` I can then use command-line git just fine.  If, in the same terminal window, I start Gitkraken it still will not recognize that I have ssh keys loaded.

If I go to Gk's settings and try to force it to use my ssh keys in `~/.ssh` I am told that Gk does not have permissions to read the dir... it is running as me, I checked.  It seems to prefer its own ssh dir in a `snap` config folder in my home dir.  I can not change that as far as I know at this time.

what am I missing?

**Edit**

Addressing @kowsky's questions below in more detail:

I have tried setting gk's auth prefs: `File` -> `Preferences` -> `Authentication`.  Under the `General` tab "use local ssh agent" is checked.  Un-checking it offers me the opportunity to brows for ssh keys.  By default Gk is pointing to an ssh dir under it's `~/snap/gitkraken/` dir.  Navigating to my `~/.ssh` dir yields a permission denied message.

My repo is on Bitbucket.org so I go to that tab and find that Gk "is connected" but trying to brows for ssh keys to add ends up with the same permission denied error.

Comment: So how did you set up your Authentication in `Preferences -> Authentication`? Did you check `Use local SSH agent`? You got the permission issue when you select the paths to your private and public keys in your `.ssh` folder, correct?

Comment: Hi, I do not have the `Authentication` option available.  It is not under `Preferences` or settings

Comment: You do not have a section `Authentication` when you open the `File -> Preferences` menu? You're sure you use GitKraken 6.0? Which OS do you use?

Comment: sorry, my fault.  I misread your note.  I thought you meant "System" Preferences... I'll check the Gitkraken prefs when I return home.

Comment: @kowsky: see the revised edit section above.  Basically, I can't get Gk to look in my `~/.ssh` folder.

Comment: This seems to be a rights issue. Is it possible to set those paths if you start GK as administrator? The other option would be to move the keys somewhere where GK does have access rights.